# Getting Object instance not set to an instance of an object error

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I am trying to encrypt user password

```
CryptoWrapper wrapObj = null;
UserDetails userDetails = dbContext.GetUserDetails();
if (userDetails != null)
{
    if (userDetails.Password !=null && userDetails.Password != "")
    {
       //some code here
       wrapObj.Crypt(userDetails.Password);
    }
}
```

I am getting "Object instance not set to an instance of an object."

Can someone help me here?

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: _where_ are you getting that exception? Which line?

Comment: Well, you are trying to reference wrapObj, which is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CryptoWrapper wrapObj = null;
```

is null and you are trying to use it.

```
wrapObj.Crypt(userDetails.Password);
```

You need to create an instance of `CryptoWrapper` and assign it to `wrapObj`

```
CryptoWrapper wrapObj = new CryptoWrapper();
```

Comment: Oops!!!This was so simple. I don't how I missed it. This is embarrassing :)

Answer (score 0):

You're setting wrapObj to null, then trying to call a method from it. Not knowing what CryptoWrapper is, you probably need to edit it to

```
CryptoAnswer wrapObj = new CryptoAnswer();
```

to initialize it.